Gitignore in subfolder to ignore any file of any project level
I wanna have a general .gitignore, which will contain dirnames and filenames of any level of a project, but put it into a subfolder. For example, I wanna ignore folder "c", project structure:
root/
├── a/
│   └── a2/
│       └── a3/
│           └── .gitignore
├── b/
│   ├── bf1.txt
│   └── bf2.txt
└── c/
    ├── cf1.txt
    └── cf2.txt

.gitignore:
c

In such case folder "c" isn't ignored for git. What should I add to make it work? Or is it even possible? Thanks!

Could you clarify what your use case is for wanting to put a top-level gitignore in a subfolder?

XY problem revealed in 5....4....3....

No, that's not possible. See the docs:

Patterns read from a .gitignore file in the same directory as the path

(emphasize mine — phd.)
That is, .gitignore in directory a/a2/a3 can only ignore files in and below a3, not above it. To ignore files everywhere .gitignore must be at the root.

No, it's not possible. Git reads patterns of files to ignore

from a .gitignore file in the same directory as the path

Source: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore
To ignore folder "c" you can put a .gitignore file in the same directory as "c" or in a parent directory.
The line
c

tells Git that you want to ignore any "c" in the current folder as well as in all of its subfolders.
If you just want to ignore the "c" in a specific folder, add a slash at the beginning of the pattern
/c

This way the pattern will only match patterns in the folder where the .gitignore resides.
